# Python mechanize error; expected name token at '<! -- Additionnal re'

Tags: python, forms, web-scraping, mechanize, bioinformatics

I am trying to write a script that will automatically upload a number of amino acid sequences to the [ExPASy myristoylator](http://web.expasy.org/myristoylator/)  but I am have trouble with the very first part. Here is what I have so far:

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("http://web.expasy.org/myristoylator/")
for i in br.forms():
    print i
```

But I keep getting the following error message back:

```
ParseError: expected name token at '<! -- Additionnal re'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out after little more Google time. The solution can be found near the end of this page on [pipermail](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2006-July/388603.html).

```
br = mechanize.Browser(factory=mechanize.RobustFactory())
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.open("http://www.expasy.org/proteomics")
response1 = br.follow_link(text_regex=r"Myristoylator", nr=1)
for i in br.forms():
    print i
```

Message me or comment on this post if you are still having trouble with this.

Cheers!